# How does sshd know which user belongs to which AuthorizedKeysFile?

Tags: ssh, openssh, sshd, key-authentication

If I set a custom path for `AuthorizedKeysFile`, how does `sshd` decide which user this key belongs to?

> AuthorizedKeysFile
>
> Specifies the file that contains the public keys that can be used for user authentication. AuthorizedKeysFile may contain tokens of the form %T which are substituted during connection setup. The following tokens are defined: %% is replaced by a literal '%', %h is replaced by the home directory of the user being authenticated, and %u is replaced by the username of that user. After expansion, AuthorizedKeysFile is taken to be an absolute path or one relative to the user's home directory. The default is ''.ssh/authorized_keys''.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sshd` doesn’t need to decide which user a key belongs to; it knows which user is attempting to connect (user on the target system), and it knows which key is provided in the attempt.

After expansion, the file pointed to by `AuthorizedKeysFile` is used to determine whether the provided key is allowed for the target user. Again, it already knows which user this is (and it needs to to replace `%u` or find the file in the first place when it’s relative to the target user’s home directory).

Comment: @finefoot with that configuration you're telling sshd that the same authorized keys file is to be used for *all* users.

Comment: No, in the default configuration an `AuthorizedKeysFile` is per-user. If you tell `sshd` to use a shared file, the keys mentioned there can be used to log in with any user.

Comment: But yes, the `AuthorizedKeysFile` *configuration directive* is global, and `%u` is the differenciator, along with the home directory of each user if a relative path is used.

Comment: Have some reputation back ;-).